# Calling .values on a column of lists returns an object array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a pandas data frame where the entries of one column are numpy arrays, all of length N. For some operations (eg. masking certain values before averaging) I would like to extract the values into an array, so that I have an object of shape (len(indices), N).

However, when I look at the .values object, it has shape (len(indices),), and then its first element has length N.

```
f = pd.DataFrame([[1,np.array([1,3,4])],[2,np.array([1,2,4])]], index=[2,5], columns=['sth','sth else'])
print np.shape(f['sth else'].values)
```

I presume this is a numpy question because there should be a way to reshape this array, but I don't know how to address this. I can of course write a for-loop and extract all individual subarrays, but was wondering if there was something more elegant that works.

Edit:
I would like to perform mask operations on the set of values for a certain key, i.e. something like this:

```
import numpy.ma as ma
print ma.masked_equal(f['sth else'].values,1)
```

which doesn't work, presumably because the array structure of f['sth else'].values is not good for it. The following does work:

```
ma.masked_equal(np.array([np.array([ 1.,  3.,  4.]) ,np.array([ 1.,  2.,  4.])]),1)
```

Comment: Please `import numpy as np`, not as `n`. Single letter module names are bad practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Listify your column and then convert. Otherwise, you have an array of arrays with `dtype=object` and it's a little hard to come back from there.

```
np.array(f['sth else'].values.tolist())

array([[1, 3, 4],
       [1, 2, 4]])
```

If this doesn't work, that means you have ragged lists (unequal length) and numpy cannot construct a contiguous integer/float array in memory for you (so will fall back to a slower, python implementation).

Comment: Ok great this works - I think it'd just need to be f['sth else'] in your answer, for consistence. Thanks though!

Comment: @mzzx Yes, thanks for that. I tend to stick to the naming conventions in my answers out of habit. Thanks!

Comment: @mzzx I think you should also adapt to naming conventions haha not sure how much time you're saving by removing one character from the conventions.. (`f` instead of `df`, `n` instead of `np` etc)

Comment: Ok perfect - yeah sorry I'm new to dataframes so haven't picked up on conventions there but should probably stick to them too... thanks both!!